# Change in url after hitting enter.

Tags: wordpress

I am using Godaddy shared hosting service and I started getting problem of change in url after hitting enter,on my all websites registered with Godaddy. I contacted them but they are not able to duplicate issue on their end. Even my clients also facings same issue. For example www.gashtalprojects.com changes to www.gashtalprojects.com/NnaXZ

Comment: I just visited the website you included in your question, and the error did not occur for me.

Comment: It worked for me too, you have a couple console errors though:
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):791 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):792

Comment: Thanks for checking in as per godaddy hosting contain malware code so they apply security and integrity filter to hosting that's why error is occurring and its intermittently appearing.